# Program cannot find the text file even though the text file is in the same folder as the code

Tags: java

I have a project for school and it's going to be transferred from my laptop to the teacher's computer for the teacher to evaluate. The problem is that my code keeps saying that the file "songlist.txt" isn't found. I am transferring the songlist.txt and the code to the teacher's computer. I made sure that I got the name of the file spelled correctly and I used a method called

`System.out.println(System.getproperty("user.dir"));`.

The out put did not show the folder where the code is in.

The output is:

> E:\Projects\Java\work which should be
>
> E:\Projects\Java\work\mp3.

I am using Ready To Program as the editor and compiler btw.

**mp3_organizer.java**

```
public class mp3_organizer
{

static BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
static final int max = 50;
static final String file = "E:\\Projects\\Java\\ICS3U Work\\src\\mp3\\songlist.txt";

public static void newsong (String file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (file, true));
    System.out.println ("[ADDING songS] \n");
    System.out.println ("Enter the name of the song");
    String name = stdin.readLine ();
    System.out.println ("Enter a file address of song");
    String filePath = stdin.readLine ();
    System.out.println ("Enter the artist's name or put N/A if unknown");
    String songArtist = stdin.readLine ();
    System.out.println ("Enter the genre");
    String songGenre = stdin.readLine ();

    writer.write ("");
    writer.newLine ();
    writer.write (name);
    writer.newLine ();
    writer.write (filePath);
    writer.newLine ();
    writer.write (songArtist);
    writer.newLine ();
    writer.write (songGenre);
    writer.newLine ();
    writer.close ();
}


static void search (String[] songname, String[] songpath, String[] artist, String[] genre, int count) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String search;
    boolean find = false;
    int select;

    System.out.println ("Please select what category you wish to search by:\n(1) song\n(2) Artist\n(3) Genre\n(4) Song Path\n(0) Cancel");
    do
    {
        select = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine ());

        switch (select)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.print ("Please enter the name of the song to search for: ");
                search = stdin.readLine ();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                {
                    if (songname [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                    {
                        find = true;
                    }
                }
                if (find)
                {
                    System.out.println ("song\tsong\tArtist\tGenre");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                    {
                        if (songname [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                        {
                            System.out.println (songname [i] + "\t" + songpath [i] + "\n" + artist [i] + "\t" + genre [i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println (search + " was not found in your library.");
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print ("Please enter the name of the artist to search for: ");
                search = stdin.readLine ();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                {
                    if (artist [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                    {
                        find = true;
                    }
                }
                if (find)
                {
                    System.out.println ("song\tsongpath\tArtist\tGenre");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                    {
                        if (artist [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                        {
                            System.out.println (songname [i] + "\t" + songpath [i] + "\n" + artist [i] + "\t" + genre [i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println ("songs by " + search + " were not found in any locations.");
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.print ("Please enter the genre to search for: ");
                search = stdin.readLine ();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                {
                    if (genre [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                    {
                        find = true;
                    }
                }
                if (find)
                {
                    System.out.println ("song\tsongpath\tArtist\tGenre");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                    {
                        if (genre [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                        {
                            System.out.println (songname [i] + "\t" + songpath [i] + "\n" + artist [i] + "\t" + genre [i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println (search + " was not found in any locations.");
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.print ("Please enter the file address of the song to search for: ");
                search = stdin.readLine ();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                {
                    if (songname [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                    {
                        find = true;
                    }
                }
                if (find)
                {
                    System.out.println ("song\tsongpath\tArtist\tGenre");
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
                    {
                        if (songname [i].equalsIgnoreCase (search))
                        {
                            System.out.println (songname [i] + "\t" + songpath [i] + "\n" + artist [i] + "\t" + genre [i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println (search + " was not found in your library.");
                }
                break;

            case 0:
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println ("Please enter a valid option: ");
        }
    }
    while (select > 3);
    System.out.println ();
}


public static void backup (String file, int count, String[] songname, String[] songpath, String[] artist, String[] genre) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("backup.txt"));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        writer.write (songname [i]);
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write (songpath [i]);
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write (artist [i]);
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write (genre [i]);
        writer.newLine ();
    }
    writer.close ();
}


public static void printlist (int count, String[] songname, String[] songpath, String[] artist, String[] genre)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println (songname [i] + "\n" + songpath [i] + "\n" + artist [i] + "\n" + genre [i]);
    }
}


public static void test ()
{
    File songlist = new File ("songlist.txt");

    System.out.println (System.getProperty ("user.dir"));

    if (songlist.exists ())
    {
        if (songlist.canRead ())
        {
            System.out.print ("file can be read");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.print ("File cannot be read");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("file does not exist");
    }
}


public static void main (String str[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{

    test();
    
    int count = 0;
    String[] songname = new String [max];
    String[] songpath = new String [max];
    String[] artist = new String [max];
    String[] genre = new String [max];

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("songlist.txt"));
    System.out.println ("[OPTIONS] \n" +
            "1) Print the song list \n" +
            "2) Add a song to list \n" +
            "3) Search for a song \n" +
            "4) Sort the song list \n" +
            "5) Create a backup of the song lsit \n" +
            "6) Delete a song from the collection \n" +
            "7) Create a new profile");

    System.out.println ("Enter a option");
    int choice = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine ());

    String temp, line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
    {
        songname [count] = line;
        songpath [count] = reader.readLine ();
        artist [count] = reader.readLine ();
        genre [count] = reader.readLine ();
        count++;
    }

    reader.close ();

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println ("[PRINTING song LIST] \n");
            printlist (count, songname, songpath, artist, genre);
            break;

        case 2:
            newsong (file);
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println ("[SONG SEARCH]");
            search (songname, songpath, artist, genre, count);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println ("[SONGLIST SORT]");

            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println ("[CREATING BACKUP OF SONGLIST");
            backup (file, count, songname, songpath, artist, genre);
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println ("[REMOVE SONG FROM LIST]");
            break;

        case 7:
            System.out.println ("[CREATE NEW PROFILE]");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Don't reference `src` in you code, it won't exist when the program is built and packaged. Instead use `mp3_organizer.class.getResource("/mp3/songlist.txt");` - this will, however mean the file is readonly, if you want to write it, then the file will need to exist in the directory from which the code is executed ie `E:\\Projects\\Java\\ICS3U Work`

Comment: WHEW! that's a lot of code. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)